# Duda const para crear plantilla

Tags: c++

Estoy con c++ aprendiendo las plantillas, pero tengo una duda, este código para crear plantillas entiendo lo que hace:

```
template <typename T> T max(T a, T b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
```

Pero dicen que si quiero **declarar la plantilla como inline + usando referencias**, entonces es así:

```
template <typename T> inline
const T& max (const T& a, const T& b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
```

Entonces no entiendo dos cosas:

El primer `T& max`: significa que la función devuelve un valor de tipo `T` ¿por referencia?
Y otra cosa que no entiendo es el `const T& max`: ¿cómo actúa el const? Qué significa para lo que devuelve?

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que estas tus dos dudas no tienen que ver específicamente con funciones templates sino con funciones en general, sus tipos de retorno y tipos de parámetros. Después, si esa función es o no es un template no cambia esos conceptos.

> El primer T& max: significa que la función devuelve un valor de tipo T
>   ¿por referencia?

max() devuelve una referencia (una referencia constante en particular. No devuelve "por referencia", devuelve "una referencia".

Y con respecto a la segunda, una función devuelve una referencia constante para que no pueda modificarse ese valor; si no fuera así se podrías asignar el valor devuelto; por ejemplo:

```
int& f(int& i)
{
    i += 10;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::cout << a << '\n';

    std::cout << f(a) << '\n'; 

    f(a) = 3;  // no parece muy útil pero va de ejemplo
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Un caso frecuente de uso de funciones que devuelven una referencia es el operador [] de una clase que representa una colección de objetos. En este caso resulta natural poner tanto

```
int n = a[i]; // asigna a n el valor de a[i]
```

como

```
a[i] = n; // asigna a a[i] el valor de n
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, que la función devuelva un valor constante lo entiendo ya con ese ejemplo, lo único que te pediría es saber si me puedes poner alguno más. Te lo comento porque en realidad, para entenderlo está bien cuando f(a) = 3; que no se pueda asignar porque es constante. Pero algún otro ejemplo más útil? Mil gracias.

Comment: @ProgrammerJr El segundo ejemplo es muy común, la sobrecarga del operador [] . Es un poco extenso para ponerme ahora, pero te paso un link donde hay un ejemplo desarrollado: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/

Answer (score 2):

Si declaras el template tal que:

```
template <typename T> T max(T a, T b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
```

La función usa `a` y `b` por valor, lo que implica que tendrá que realizar una copia de los parámetros par poder trabajar con ellos. Si usas la función con, por ejemplo enteros:

```
int a = 5, b = 10;
std::cout << max(a,b);
```

Sin embargo imagínate que en vez de un tipo nativo estás comparando objetos un poco más pesados:

```
struct dato
{
  int* listado; // supongamos que tiene varios millones de elementos
  int tam_listado;

  std::vector<int> otroListado; // supongamos que tiene otros tantos

  // otros miembros
  // ...

  // constructor copia
  dato(dato const& b)
    : listado(new int[b.tam_listado]),
      tam_listado(b.tam_listado),
      otroListado(b.otroListado),
      /* ... */
  {
    for(int i=0; i<tam_listado; i++)
      listado[i] = b.listado[i];
  }

  // para que funcione max()
  bool operator<(dato const& b) const
  { /* ... */ }
};

// para que funcione cout
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, dato const& a)
{ /* ... */ }


dato d1, d2;
cout << max(d1,d2);
```

Lo que sucede es que el programa realiza ahora dos copias de objetos pesados para poder usarlos de forma local y eso puede llegar a penalizar seriamente el rendimiento... además habrá situaciones en las que los objetos no admitirán la realización de copias (pueden tener el constructor copia deshabilitado)... lo que te impedirá directamente utilizar la función.

La segunda versión que propones:

```
template <typename T> inline
const T& max (const T& a, const T& b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
```

Tiene como ventaja principal que evita crear copias locales, lo que previene cuellos de botella al usar la función con objetos pesados. Desde luego es mejor opción que la primera a pesar que puede penalizar levemente el rendimiento con tipos nativos (una referencia *puede* implicar una indirección)

Sin embargo la versión dista de ser perfecta. En el caso de los objetos pesados imagina que sucede con esta instrucción:

```
dato d1, d2;
d1 = max(d1,d2);
```

Estás haciendo una copia pesada que, con la configuración actual, no podrás evitar.

¿Hay alternativas mejores?

Si te mueves a algun estándar no arcaico (C++11 en adelante), tienes a tu disposición una característica llamada *sintaxis move* (hay algunas entradas al respecto en SOes). Esta nueva característica viene acompañada de un nuevo constructor y operador de asignación:

```
Clase::Clase(Clase && param);

Clase& Clase::operator=(Clase && param);
```

Esta sintaxis está pensada para optimizar operaciones en las que se involucran objetos pesados. Las dos nuevas funciones cuyo prototipo has visto encima de este párrafo se invocan en determinadas situaciones y permiten *mover* punteros y otros objetos internos de una instancia a otra (en vez de realizar una copia de los mismos)... no me voy a explayar en esta parte porque eso sería otra pregunta diferente.

El caso es que con esto en mente lo mejor es aprovechar directamente esta característica para diseñar la función:

```
template <typename T> T max(T && a, T && b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
```

A primera vista parece que lo tiene todo ya que usa la *sintaxis move*, la cual es lo suficientemente inteligente como para convertirse en una copia si el tipo `T` tiene deshabilitada dicha característica... ¿o no?

Lo cierto es que la función no cumple del todo con su misión:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> T max(T && a, T && b) { return a < b ? b : a; }

struct POO
{
  POO() = default;
  POO(POO &&)
  { std::cout << "move\n"; }
  POO(POO const&)
  { std::cout << "copy\n"; }

  bool operator<(POO const&) const
  { return true; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, POO const&)
{
  return os << 1;
}

int main()
{
  POO a, b;
  POO c = max(a,b);
  POO d = max(std::move(a),std::move(b));
  std::cout << c << d; // Para evitar warnings por variables sin uso
}
```

El programa mostrará el siguiente resultado:

```
copy
copy
11
```

Cuando lo esperable habría sido

```
copy
move
11
```

¿Qué ha pasado?

Bueno, para no enrollarnos con un exceso de teoría podemos dejarlo en que el compilador necesita una pequeña ayuda para resolver correctamente el retorno de la función. Esa ayudita se denomina *perfect forwarding* y, aplicándola, el programa quedaría así:

```
template <typename T> T max(T && a, T && b)
{ return a < b ? std::forward<T>(b) : std::forward<T>(a); }
```

Si ahora probamos el ejemplo el programa nos devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
copy
move
11
```

Con lo que, ahora sí, tenemos una función que se adapta perfectamente a todos los usos posibles

Y ahora, respondiendo a otras dudas...

> El primer T& max: significa que la función devuelve un valor de tipo T ¿por referencia?

Lo que significa es que va a devolver una referencia a un valor... y que ese valor va a ser de tipo T.

Entendiendo un poco las referencias con un ejemplo:

```
int  a = 5;
int  b = a; // copia
int& c = a; // referencia

b = 6; // solo afecta a b
c = 7; // al ser una referencia, a tambien cambiará

std::cout << a << b << c; // Imprime 767
```

> ¿cómo actúa el const?

Al usar `const` se impiden modificaciones sobre los parámetros. Es un mecanismo de protección que indica que los parámetros `a` y `b` no van a verse modificados de ninguna manera después de llamar a la función.

Por otro lado, `const` es necesario en este caso porque en caso contrario no podrías hacer esto:

```
std::cout << max(5,6);
```

Ya que esos números escritos a fuego en el código no pueden ser gestionados con referencias no constantes... ¿Qué sucede si intentas modificar el valor a través de la referencia?

> Qué significa para lo que devuelve?

La función recibe dos referencias constantes, luego lo único que podría devolver es o un valor `T` (que implica copias) o una referencia constante (para respetar los tipos).

El devolver una referencia constante permite evitar la realización de copias en determinadas circunstancias:

```
int c  = max(a,b); // se hace una copia
int& d = max(a,b); // No hace copia
```